# How do i fetch user's location, homeTown & email id in facebook Integration in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook Sdk to get user data , I am getting all other user data instead of email - id , user's location and user's home town.

below here is the code which i have implemented.

```
-(void)facebookLogin
{
    NSArray *permissionsNeeded = @[@"basic_info",@"email",@"user_about_me",@"public_profile"];

    NSArray *permissions = @[@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown",@"user_location",@"email",@"basic_info"];
    loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:permissions];

    loginView.frame = CGRectMake(42, 349, 115, 40);

    [self.view addSubview:loginView];

    loginView.delegate = self;      
}

-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
    NSLog(@"%@", user);

    facebookID = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
}
```

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

can you try inside of `loginViewFetchedUserInfo:user:` the following

```
//id<FBGraphUser> user = (id<FBGraphUser>)result;
NSString * faceId = [user objectID];
NSLog(@"faceId:%@", faceId);
id<FBGraphPlace> fbPlace = [user location];
NSLog(@"fbPlace name:%@", [fbPlace name]);
id<FBGraphLocation> fbLocation = [fbPlace location];
NSString * userCity = [fbLocation objectForKey:@"city"];
NSLog(@"userCity:%@", userCity);
NSString * userCountry = [fbLocation country];
NSLog(@"userCountry:%@", userCountry);
NSString * userZip = [fbLocation objectForKey:@"zip"];
NSLog(@"userZip:%@", userZip);
NSString * birthday = [user birthday];
NSLog(@"birthday:%@", birthday);
NSString * email = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
NSLog(@"email:%@", email);
NSString * name = [user name];
NSLog(@"facebook name:%@", name);
```

Comment: no its not working, actually the problem is that my facebookApp id is not able to fetch user location, hometown, profile pic.that's why everything is going null except email id and facebook name.